# Docker container and virtual python environment

Tags: python, docker

I'm getting started working with Docker. I installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 and downloaded the desired container. I need full access to container’s filesystem with the ability to add and edit files. Can I transfer the contents of the container into a Virtual Python Environment in Windows filesystem? How to do it?

Comment: It would be a minor pain, but you could move  files back and forth using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/). Why do you need to move files into and out of the container? Perhaps there is another approach?

Comment: I don't need to move files into the container, just extract files for learning, editing and adding new files.  Can I do that with docker volumes? The links between files and correct functioning of the program will not be broken?

Comment: If you just want to play with the docker container, after you started the container, run `docker exec -it [container name] /bin/bash`. All file you changed will be removed once you deleted the playground container.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring files between Windows and Linux might be a little annoying because of [different line endings](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/).

Putting that aside, sounds like you are looking to create a Docker based development environment.  There are good tutorials online that walk you through setting one up, I would start with one of these

1. [Running a Rails Development Environment in Docker](https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/). This one is about Rails, but the principles will be the same. Section 3 specifically talks about about sharing code between your host machine and the Docker container.
2. [How To Work with Docker Data Volumes on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-docker-data-volumes-on-ubuntu-14-04) includes an brief introduction to Docker containers, different use cases for [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/), and how to get each one working. *Sharing Data Between the Host and the Docker Container* section talks about what you are trying to do. This example talks about reading log files created inside the container, but the principle is the same for adding/updating files in the container.